# terraform dynamic bloc with two iterations

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I have a dynamic bloc in terraform which content has two dynamic arguments as we can't use for_each twice in the same bloc is there a way to use dynamic bloc in this case

```
locals {  
   mx_server = [ "smtp.mydomain.com.", "mail.mydomain.com."]
   preference = [ 5, 10 ]
}

resource "dns_mx_record_set" "mx" {
  for_each = toset(var.dns_zones)
  zone = "${each.value}."
  ttl  = 300

  dynamic "mx" {
    for_each = toset(local.mx_server)
    content {
      exchange = mx.value
      preference = 10
    }    
  }
}
```

Here I would like to iterate also on preference argument. What is expected as result is the same thing if I don't use any iteration

```
resource "dns_mx_record_set" "mx" {
  for_each = toset(var.dns_zones)
  zone = "${each.value}."
  ttl  = 300

  "mx" {
      exchange = smtp.mydomain.com
      preference = 5
    }
 "mx" {
      exchange = mail.mydomain.com
      preference = 10
    }
  }
}
```

the question is how to loop on `exchange` and `preference` argument at the same time when I can't use `for_each` twice in the same block

Comment: Is the preference related in any way to the order in `mx_server`?

Comment: If I remember how `MX` records work correctly it seems strange to declare the same `MX` hostname twice with different preference numbers. Could you clarify what you're asking by editing your question to include an example of how it would look if you hand-wrote all of the individual `mx` blocks manually? Then folks answering the question can suggest how to achieve that same result using a dynamic rule instead.

Comment: Got it, I'll update my post to highlight what expected

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do to overcome your problem?

Comment: Not yet the solution provided doesn't work fine it adds the required data twice

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setproduct](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setproduct):

```
resource "dns_mx_record_set" "mx" {
  for_each = toset(var.dns_zones)
  zone = "${each.value}."
  ttl  = 300

  dynamic "mx" {
    for_each = setproduct(local.mx_server, local.preference)
    content {
      exchange = mx.value[0]
      preference = mx.value[1]
    }    
  }
}
```